# Node/Express JS authentication: what else other than Passport JS?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I usually make websites using Javascript (JQuery) client side, and use PHP + MySQL server side for user authentication, online ordering system etc.

I have been learning node/express, socket.io, mongoDB/mongoose and passport for a few months and is thinking of using them in production to replace the PHP + MySQL server side and allow my website to be more real-time/interactive. Users of my site are tech savvy and so browser compatibility is not an issue.

Is Passport the only production level **local** authentication system for node/express? (usernames/passwords stored locally on my server via mongoDB)

Comment: There is everyauth and node-oauth, in addition to passport.

Comment: Do everyauth and node-oauth work for usernames/passwords that are stored locally on my server via mongoDB? Sorry, it wasn't obvious from a quick glance.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry. I made the assumption that you would be doing more than local authentication and would want automation for 3rd party services. Passport is the only one I know of that does local.

Comment: @MattBakaitis - Thanks. I will update the question to make sure its clear to others too.

Comment: I guess since Strongloop (http://strongloop.com/products) also uses mongoose/mongoDB and passport, I must be on the right track...

Answer (score 1):

The only other local authentication node module I have come accross is called lockit. I personally have not used it but it seems like it has much less overhead than passport. Then again, Passport is extremely customizable and powerful.

[Getting started with lockit](http://www.mircozeiss.com/lockit-an-express-authentication-solution/)

[Git Repo](https://github.com/zeMirco/lockit)